# How do I get the underlying bytes of a Cassandra query using the C# driver?

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm trying to get the underlying byte array from Cassandra queries using the C# driver. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v3.spec

Does anyone know how to get the byte array?

I've tried looking for some kind of "toBytes" method, but I can't find it and I'm not sure if I'm even using the right driver or if there's one that's better suited for this.

Comment: You mean the byte arrays of query result, or byte array with data in blob?

Comment: I mean the byte array of the query. Like the Cassandra protocol bits (with the header and all) that represents a query. I don't intend on sending a query to the database, I just want to know how it gets parsed/serialized and sent over the network as a packet.

Answer (score 0):

The driver doesn't expose the request in the API.

If you want to know how that is built, you can look into the source code: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/3.10.1/src/Cassandra/Requests/QueryRequest.cs